# How to save application state on Android

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:** 
>   [How do I save an Android application's state?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151777/how-do-i-save-an-android-applications-state)

I have an Android app. The app crashes in one screen and the app exits. When I launch the app again, I need to launch another screen by checking some condition in the initial activity onCreate() method. Can we do this using preferences or SQLite?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You must override the `onSaveInstanceState` method. You can use preferences or SQLite, too.

Here's your exact duplicate question with code samples.

- *[How do save an Android Activity state using save instance state?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151777/how-do-i-save-an-android-applications-state)*

Comment: Absolutely correct.  And to elaborate: you can certainly "save state" with sharedPreferences and/or with SQLite.  But in this case, Android "Bundles" are your friend.

Comment: Do you need to implement the override method in a custom `Application` subclass?

Comment: @Eido95: No, the method override is on your Activity class. See the documentation for it.
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onSaveInstanceState(android.os.Bundle)